# How to use group by, order by and where condition in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given table contains

```
employee_id, 
Month_Year, 
Salary, 
City
```

Write a query to get fifth highest yearly paid employee from every city.

my code:

```
select * from (select * from(select * from (select * from dummy order by sal desc) where rownum <= 5)  order by sal) where rownum <=1 ;
```

but this gives only the 5th highest in the total table.

where am i suppose to use group  by statement ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your SQL query seams to be Oracle database related not MySQL.. Because it seams you are using Oracle database puedocolumn rownum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select *
from tablename as t1 
where 
  t1.salary = (select salary from tablename t2
             where 
             t2.city= t1.city ORDER by salary desc limit 1 offset 5)
```

Comment: offset 4 or 5 ?

Comment: it should be 4 @Nivedh

Answer (score 0):

The following query is working for me. (number(4) in where condition is 'N' where 'N' is nth highest salary. In your case you want 5th highest salary so N-1 is 4)

[find nth highest salary in sql](https://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/)

```
select salary,city 
FROM tablename n1
WHERE (4) = (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(n2.Salary))
FROM tablename n2
WHERE n2.Salary > n1.Salary and n1.city=n2.city group by n2.city)
```